# Daily Kernel Panic on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic, restart

My MacBook Pro kernel panics daily. I have clean-installed Mavericks yet it's not fixed. Could you tell me what is wrong from these reports?

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8006adbf5e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8006aa4090, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000074, CR3: 0x000000006c53606a, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0xffffff80070d0320, RBX: 0x0000000000000060, RCX: 0x0000000000000060, RDX: 0x000000000000006c
RSP: 0xffffff809a56bd00, RBP: 0xffffff809a56bd20, RSI: 0xffffff800cc5c440, RDI: 0xffffff80070d0920

R8:  0xffffff800ced37f8, R9:  0xffffff800ce68140, R10: 0x000000010a0b8000, R11: 0x00007fff93155c90
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff801da5e0e0, R14: 0x000000000000009f, R15: 0xffffff800ce68140
RFL: 0x0000000000010296, RIP: 0xffffff8006aa4090, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000074, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff809a56b990 : 0xffffff8006a22fa9
0xffffff809a56ba10 : 0xffffff8006adbf5e
0xffffff809a56bbe0 : 0xffffff8006af3456
0xffffff809a56bc00 : 0xffffff8006aa4090
0xffffff809a56bd20 : 0xffffff8006aa4d35
0xffffff809a56bd50 : 0xffffff8006a78e03
0xffffff809a56bf20 : 0xffffff8006adc39c
0xffffff809a56bfb0 : 0xffffff8006af335b

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: com.apple.WebKit

Mac OS version:
13D65

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: ADD73AE6-88B0-32FB-A8BB-4F7C8BE4092E
Kernel slide:     0x0000000006800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8006a00000
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 160319367955
last loaded kext at 57897334464: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.60 (addr 0xffffff7f88547000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.kerio.kext.kvnet    8.3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor    1.9.5d0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver    2.6.1f2
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer    1.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver    1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM    100.14.15
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.5.13
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl    3.5.26
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver    2.6.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA    2.6.1f2
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000    1.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics    8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight    170.3.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU    4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP    1.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC    1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    1.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter    104
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl    1.1.12
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport    4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.5.26
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons    240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver    240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard    240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController    325.7
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient    3.6.6
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver    3.0.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter    404
com.apple.BootCache    35
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    666.4.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC    1.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331    700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI    660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI    656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    3.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager    161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET    1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient    217.92.1
com.apple.security.quarantine    3
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall    153
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement    217.92.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface    91.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily    10.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily    4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib    2.6.1f2
com.apple.vecLib.kext    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily    1.9.7fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily    98.20
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController    2.6.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily    2.6.1f2
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport    1.2.2
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.5.26
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController    1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport    4.2.4f1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI    1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl    3.5.26
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC    3.1.8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily    5.7.0d11
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter    3.1.7
com.apple.kext.triggers    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    1.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch    240.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub    650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite    656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice    3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily    1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily    1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily    1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    2.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily    3.2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI    2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily    3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController    1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient    1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient    660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family    630.35
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily    677.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily    2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily    1.1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet    7
com.apple.security.sandbox    278.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily    23
com.apple.driver.DiskImages    371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore    2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore    28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily    2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread    1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.69f3
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533642465238432D48392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533642465238432D48392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.4f1 13674, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST9500325ASG, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

[image: Console Screenshot]

This macbook pro was updated to Yosemite and the kernel panic occurred, then it's downgraded to 10.9.3, and now I clean-installed 10.9.2 on it to see if the problem went away but it's still there.

I deleted AudioAUUC.kext but it's still happening. here is the new kernel panic report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       22AA7F8A-E769-8811-63C8-C86C0903F315

Wed Feb 18 13:54:24 2015
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80070dbe2e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80070a3f40, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000014, CR3: 0x0000000049bb404e, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0xffffff80076d0320, RBX: 0x0000000000000054, RCX: 0x0000000000000054, RDX: 0x000000000000000c
RSP: 0xffffff808625b350, RBP: 0xffffff808625b370, RSI: 0xffffff800d150440, RDI: 0xffffff80076d0860
R8:  0xffffff800d2b73f8, R9:  0xffffff800d3264a0, R10: 0xffffff807206e314, R11: 0xffffff807206e004
R12: 0x0000000000000003, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x000000000000012b, R15: 0xffffff800d3264a0
RFL: 0x0000000000010292, RIP: 0xffffff80070a3f40, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000014, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff808625afe0 : 0xffffff8007022fa9 
0xffffff808625b060 : 0xffffff80070dbe2e 
0xffffff808625b230 : 0xffffff80070f3326 
0xffffff808625b250 : 0xffffff80070a3f40 
0xffffff808625b370 : 0xffffff800707b183 
0xffffff808625b440 : 0xffffff800707bd5a 
0xffffff808625b470 : 0xffffff800702aaa9 
0xffffff808625b4a0 : 0xffffff800702b179 
0xffffff808625b4d0 : 0xffffff7f88b059d8 
0xffffff808625b4f0 : 0xffffff800747075b 
0xffffff808625b520 : 0xffffff80074704b8 
0xffffff808625b5e0 : 0xffffff7f88b0604d 
0xffffff808625b770 : 0xffffff7f88b07414 
0xffffff808625b800 : 0xffffff7f88b075d4 
0xffffff808625b850 : 0xffffff8007214e81 
0xffffff808625b8a0 : 0xffffff8007214ad7 
0xffffff808625b950 : 0xffffff800736fc63 
0xffffff808625ba10 : 0xffffff80071ffab7 
0xffffff808625ba80 : 0xffffff800743813c 
0xffffff808625bb20 : 0xffffff800706d464 
0xffffff808625bb70 : 0xffffff800706c8c3 
0xffffff808625bbb0 : 0xffffff8007074ee2 
0xffffff808625bd50 : 0xffffff80070787a4 
0xffffff808625bf20 : 0xffffff80070dc26c 
0xffffff808625bfb0 : 0xffffff80070f322b 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib(1.0d1)[E163B7AE-F6E5-3286-B827-66DB3FE3DB7B]@0xffffff7f88b05000->0xffffff7f88b08fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Safari

Mac OS version:
13C64

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9FEA8EDC-B629-3ED2-A1A3-6521A1885953
Kernel slide:     0x0000000006e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8007000000
System model name: MacBookPro8,2 (Mac-94245A3940C91C80)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 69091994061
last loaded kext at 42277356075: com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0 (addr 0xffffff7f88a02000, size 36864)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.AppleTyMCEDriver   1.0.2d2
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.15
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.0f1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.4.35
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.2.4
com.apple.AMDRadeonX3000    1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.35
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter  104
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 1.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.6
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    666.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.0f1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.5fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.3f10
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 98.14
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.3f10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.35
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.0d10
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.2.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.35
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.0f1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.0f1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    3.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.4.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    2.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 3.2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   630.35
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 675.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.69f3
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533642465238432D48392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333235533642465238432D48392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.3f10 13477, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Serial ATA Device: ST9500325ASG, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: v165w
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 2
```

Comment: I'd try at least updating to 10.9.5 - 13D65 comes up as 10.9.3 on Google. I'd also pull Kerio out of the equation; some versions known to conflict with Mavericks.

Comment: @Tetsujin I added some futher information in the original post, thx again

Comment: Having the same problem @HiradA Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Do you have any external devices physically connected? Additionally, see my comment on the answer given. You were given bad advice. If you deleted that kernel extension, you will need to reinstall OSX. If you removed/unloaded it, reload it and use `kextstat` to make sure it's back in place. The third party kernel extension may have been the one actually causing the original panic.  Lastly, see [Resolving Kernel Panics](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/kernelpanics.html) to isolate the issue and hopefully resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

In your log is the following line:

```
last loaded kext at 57897334464: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC
```

Did you try to uninstall this kext? Perhaps this might help.
I had a similar problem with a driver for a usb-serial adapter. Removing the kext solved the problem.

Comment: I added some futher information in the original post, thx again.

Comment: This is bad advice. Removing Apple signed kernel extensions can cause a ton of problems, especially if there are dependencies. One of those problems includes kernel panics.